# jquery set current class on anchor tags

Tags: jquery

I currently have this jquery code to set the current class, I am a bit of a novice with jquery and would like to know how to make this cleaner and more compact. It currently works but I would like to know how to do it better.

```
// add class current
$('.textResizing ul .normal a').click(function () {
    $('.textResizing ul .normal a').addClass('current');
    $('.textResizing ul .medium a').removeClass('current');
    $('.textResizing ul .large a').removeClass('current');
});

$ ('.textResizing ul .medium a').click(function () {
    $('.textResizing ul .medium a').addClass('current');
    $('.textResizing ul .normal a').removeClass('current');
    $('.textResizing ul .large a').removeClass('current');
});

$ ('.textResizing ul .large a').click(function () {
    $('.textResizing ul .large a').addClass('current');
        $('.textResizing ul .normal a').removeClass('current');
    $('.textResizing ul .medium a').removeClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your html looks like but something like this? :

```
$('.textResizing ul a').click(function () {
    $('.textResizing ul a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: FANTASTIC!!!!, one more thing I am using this on an accesibility font size switcher on thetop of the page, is there any way to get cookies to remember the current state? I am using the cookies plugin. Thanks!!

Comment: Jut create another question. Your second question is out of the topic here. The outcome is that no one with similar problem will find that question on stackoverflow. And worst of all, they won’t find the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, firs of all you can cache selectors. It’s the easiest and the most useful optimization in jq because each time you use seletors, jq needs to parse dom to find elements. So:

```
// add class current
var na = $('.textResizing ul .normal a'),
    ma = $('.textResizing ul .medium a'),
    la = $('.textResizing ul .large a');

na.click(function () {
   this.addClass('current');
   ma.removeClass('current');
   la.removeClass('current');
});

ma.click(function () {
   this.addClass('current');
   na.removeClass('current');
   la.removeClass('current');
});

la.click(function () {
   this.addClass('current');
   na.removeClass('current');
   ma.removeClass('current');
});
```